# Let $X=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x = 0 \text{ or } x^2+y^2 \in \Bbb Q\} \subset \Bbb R^2$. Is $X$ connected? Is it locally-connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

> Let $X=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x = 0 \text{ or } x^2+y^2 \in \Bbb Q\} \subset \Bbb R^2$. Is $X$ connected? Is it locally-connected?

$X$ is the $y$-axis union rational points on the unit disc. I think this is not connected as the rational points are "discrete", but I don't know how to formalize this. Can I use the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is not connected?

For the latter part I know that $\Bbb Q$ is also not locally-connected, but I don't think I can argue with just this since there is also the condition $x=0$. What is the way to figure out whether the set is locally connected or not?

Comment: "$X$ is the $y$-axis union rational points on the unit disc"... this is wrong! For instance, $(2, 2)$ is also a point on $X$. Try to find where you went wrong.

Comment: If the set had actually been the $y$-axis union rational points on the unit disc, then you should use a similar proof to the standard way to show $\Bbb Q$ is disconnected - exhibit some open sets that disconnect it. In the case of $\Bbb Q$, you can use that there are "gaps" at the irrationals, so you can look at some sets like $(-\infty, \sqrt 2)$ and $(\sqrt 2, \infty)$. A similar idea would work for that set.

Comment: You could view $X$ as the union of the sets $\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2| x=0, x^2+y^2=q  \}$ for $q$ that varies in $\mathbb Q^+$ (hence every set its basically the union of the line $\{x=0\}$ with a  circumference  ).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $X$ consists of the $y$-axis united to all the circumferences with center $0$ and rational square of the radius (since it is the squared norm of $(x,y)$ which has to be rational).

This is a good example of a connected but not locally connected space. It is clearly path-connected because you can move from one of the circumferences to another one just by reaching the $y$-axis and going up or down on it. However, it is not locally connected because if you restrict your attention to a small open neighborhood $U=B \cap X$ of a point in $X$ $\backslash \left\{ x=0 \right\}$ (with $B$ being a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$) then, chosen a suitable $t$ such that $t^2 \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $B$ intersects the circumference with radius $t$, the sets
$$C_1=\left\{ (x,y) \in U : x^2 + y^2 \leq t^2\right\}$$
$$C_2=\left\{ (x,y) \in U : x^2 + y^2 \geq t^2\right\}$$
form a partition of two closed non-empty disjoint subsets.

Comment: The square of the radius is rational, not necessarily the radius itself.

Comment: Ok fixed. Does not change so much though

Comment: @DarkMagician I don't quite understand your solution. I think the local connectivity doesn't work since if I pick a point at one of the circumferences and take an open ball around it I have a "bunch" of disjoint lines inside the ball so the ball would not be connected, but why do you require $t^2 \notin \Bbb Q$ and what are these $C_1$ and $C_2$ sets?

Comment: Well, your argument can just prove that the neighborhood is not  path-connected. Being not connected is a stronger condition, do you know the difference?

Comment: A topological space is said to be **connected** if there is no couple of disjoint non-empty closed subsets whose union is the whole space. Instead, a space is **path-connected** if any couple points is linked by a continuous curve (a path). A path-connected space is connected, but the converse does not hold.

Comment: My argument consists in separating $U$ in the points whose squared norm is $\leq t^2$ and the ones whose squared norm is $\geq t^2$. These two subsets are obviously closed and are disjoint because points whose squared norm is $t^2$ are inacceptable. Note that I edited the answer, there was a slight mistake in the definition of $t$.